# error ejecutando ionic cordova build android

Tags: cordova, ionic3, gradle

**Aquí pongo lo que devuelve la consola al ejecutar ionic cordova build android.**

```
Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova  
[08:42:07]  build dev started ...  
[08:42:07]  clean started ...  
[08:42:07]  clean finished in 27 ms  
[08:42:07]  copy started ...  
[08:42:07]  deeplinks started ...  
[08:42:07]  deeplinks finished in 33 ms  
[08:42:07]  transpile started ...  
[08:42:14]  transpile finished in 6.56 s  
[08:42:14]  preprocess started ...  
[08:42:14]  preprocess finished in 1 ms  
[08:42:14]  webpack started ...  
[08:42:14]  copy finished in 7.39 s  
[08:42:22]  webpack finished in 8.20 s  
[08:42:22]  sass started ...  
Without `from` option PostCSS could generate wrong source map and will not find Browserslist config. Set it to CSS file  
path or to `undefined` to prevent this warning.  
[08:42:23]  sass finished in 1.42 s  
[08:42:23]  postprocess started ...  
[08:42:23]  postprocess finished in 7 ms  
[08:42:23]  lint started ...  
[08:42:23]  build dev finished in 16.56 s  
> cordova build android  
[08:42:28]  lint finished in 4.93 s  
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Data_Bank\Programming\sdk  
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_40

:preBuild

:compileDebugNdk

UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild

:checkDebugManifest

:CordovaLib:compileLint

:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint
 UP-TO-DATE

:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles
 UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:preBuild

:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild

:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest

:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies

:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl
 UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript

UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets  
 UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources  
 UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources  
 UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest  
 UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava  

UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes  
 UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJar  
 UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk  
 UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE  
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE  
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE  
:prepareDebugDependencies  
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE  
:compileDebugRenderscript  
 UP-TO-DATE  
:generateDebugBuildConfig  
 UP-TO-DATE  
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE  
:mergeDebugAssets  
 UP-TO-DATE  
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE  
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE  
:mergeDebugResources  
 UP-TO-DATE

:processDebugManifest

UP-TO-DATE  
:processDebugResources

UP-TO-DATE  
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE  
:compileDebugJava

UP-TO-DATE  
:preDexDebug

UP-TO-DATE  
:dexDebug

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:  
java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\Diseño\MyProject\BlankProject\platform\android\build\intermediates\classes\debug:  
file not found

        at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)  
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)  
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:677)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:  
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Diseño\MyProject\BlankProject\platforms\android\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-500b7bd00168cf40817e644228da5b645c284d5c.jar (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)

        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:677)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
 FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 30.727 secs

        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)  
2 errors; aborting

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        D:\Data_Bank\Programming\sdk\build-tools\25.0.0\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Dise?o\MyProject\BlankProject\platforms\android\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Dise?o\MyProject\BlankProject\platforms\android\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt  
Error Code:
        1
Output:

        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
        java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\Diseño\MyProject\BlankProject\platforms\android\build\intermediates\classes
\debug: file not found

                at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:677)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
                at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Diseño\MyProject\BlankProject\platforms\android\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-500b7bd00168cf40817e644228da5b645c284d5c.jar (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)

                at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
                at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
                at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
                at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
                at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:677)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
                at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
                at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
        2 errors; aborting


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1).
```

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta estas en **SO en Español**

Comment: todo está en español lo demás es lo que devuelve la consola al ejecutar "ionic cordova build android".

Comment: si lo siento no habia visto la pregunta

Comment: me parece que no está instalada la plataforma, ya que no encuentra archivos... ¿ cordova add platform android ?

Comment: La plataforma está instalada pero dice que falta un archivo y los errores son ahí (java.lang.RuntimeException: file not found y java.io.FileNotFoundException: (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada))

Comment: Prueba a reinstalar la plataforma, a ver si eso cambia algo.

Comment: ES LA Ñ !!! , apostaría a que es la Ñ en la ruta

Comment: Eso había pensado pero cuando busco en la ruta el archivo que está tratando de ejecutar no existe

Comment: entonces como dice Álvaro, reinstalar la plataforma, a ver que pasa